# Return object in function after JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new in android dev and I have an issue with my code. I'm trying to parse data from a json, put the information into an object and then return this from a function.

My code:

```
data class AccountInfo (
    var username: String,
    var bio: String,
    var avatar: String,
    var cover: String,
    var created: Long,
    var reputation: Double
)


fun getAccountInfo(accessToken: String): AccountInfo {
        var info = AccountInfo("username", "", "", "", 0, 0.0)

        val jsonObjectRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, "https://api.imgur.com/3/account/me", null, Response.Listener { response ->
            Log.e(HomeFragment.TAG, "got $response")
            try {
                val data = JSONObject(response.toString())
                val items = data.getJSONObject("data")

                Log.e(HomeFragment.TAG, "username=" + items.getString("url"))

                info.username = items.getString("url")

                Log.e(HomeFragment.TAG, "username second=" + info.username)

                info.bio = items.getString("bio")
                info.avatar = items.getString("avatar")
                info.cover = items.getString("cover")
                info.created = items.getLong("created")
                info.reputation = items.getDouble("reputation")

            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                Log.e(HomeFragment.TAG, "Parsing error: " + e.message)
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Log.e(HomeFragment.TAG, "Response error: " + error.message)
        }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${accessToken}"
                headers["User-Agent"] = "epicture"
                return headers
            }
        }

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.instance?.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)

        Log.e(HomeFragment.TAG, "username last=" + info.username)

        return info
    }
```

The problem is that the function always returns default initialized object (with "username" for username for exemple) and not the string parsed in my JsonObjectRequest, even if the parsing is working (logs are correct)...

If you have some help or ideas thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until  **JsonObjectRequest**   has finished and returned the result from server then you got the result , You get the result inside **Response.Listener**  callback but the  **info** object that you returned doesn't updated.
use async wait or a suspend function to fetch info from server then return it

**Update :**

Here is the code :

```
fun getAccountInfo(
    accessToken: String,
    onSuccess: (account: AccountInfo) -> Unit,
    onError: (e: Exception) -> Unit
) {
    val jsonObjectRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
        Method.GET,
        "https://api.imgur.com/3/account/me",
        null,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            try {
                val data = JSONObject(response.toString())
                val items = data.getJSONObject("data")
                val info = AccountInfo(
                    username = items.getString("url"),
                    bio = items.getString("bio"),
                    avatar = items.getString("avatar"),
                    cover = items.getString("cover"),
                    created = items.getLong("created"),
                    reputation = items.getDouble("reputation")
                )
                onSuccess.invoke(info) // request success so call this
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                onError.invoke(e)
            }
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            onError.invoke(error)
        }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $accessToken"
            headers["User-Agent"] = "epicture"
            return headers
        }
    }

   AppController.instance?.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```

**Call this on your Activity**

```
  getAccountInfo("access token",
            onSuccess = {
                // todo show info in UI
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: onSuccess : $it")
            },
            onError = {
                // toast error or show custom error view
                Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: onError: ", it)
            }
        )
```

Comment: even if I do:

        doAsync {

            var info = Imgur.getAccountInfo(parameters.second.accessToken)

            val text: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.textview_account) as TextView
            text.text = info.username;

        }.execute()

I have the same result. info.username is still "username"